# Customer status active

Tags: database, customer, magento-1

In which database table can I find the field that contains the "information"
(true or false) if the customer is active or not.

Like in the Backend "customer acc. active".

Comment: Seems you are using a 3rd party module?! Please add the info to your question.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I'm not using 3rd party mod. in this case. I need the information for a query for my own statistic. But I cant find the table with the wanted information.

Comment: I use magento 1.8 but i think it doesn't matter which Version.

Comment: There is no such thing. If you go through the database, you will find a colum is_active in the customer_entity table but this colum is not in use. So I'm afraid you cannot accomplish this unless you extend the functionality to enable/disable customers on your own.

Comment: Yes I find the colum "is_active" and I thought it will the right one. But all values (in this case 1) are the same. So I have to create an additional attribut for this. But where get the Backend the data active yes/no?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl. You should write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing. If you go through the database, you will find a colum is_active in the customer_entity table but this colum is not in use. So I'm afraid you cannot accomplish this unless you extend the functionality to enable/disable customers on your own.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "is active" in the backend, you are probably referring to "is confirmed".

It is based on the EAV attribute "confirmation", which contains the confirmation code. If it is empty, the customer is confirmed.

This means, you can find the information in the value table `customer_entity_varchar`. For example, for a customer with ID 42, run:

```
SELECT v.* FROM customer_entity_varchar v
INNER JOIN eav_attribute a ON a.attribute_id=v.attribute_id
WHERE attribute_code='confirmation' AND v.entity_id=42 AND value IS NOT NULL
```

if this query returns any result, the customer is **not confirmed**